# Dining philosophers using channels

Tags: go, synchronization, dining-philosophers

I have the following code to solve dinning philosophers problem using Go channels and am looking for review comments:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "sync"
    "os"
    "bufio"
)


type diner struct {
    thinkTime time.Duration
    eatTime time.Duration
    free []chan bool
    done []chan bool
    n int
    c  *sync.Cond
    started chan int
}

func newDiner(n int,eatTime time.Duration,thinkTime time.Duration) *diner {

    d := new(diner)
    d.n = n
    // first create n fork channels and philo channels as communication between forks and philosophers
    d.free = make([]chan bool,n)
    d.done = make([]chan bool,n)

    d.c = sync.NewCond(&sync.Mutex {} )

    d.thinkTime = thinkTime
    d.eatTime = eatTime

    // make a buffered channel
    d.started = make(chan int,n)

    for i:=0;i<n;i++{
        d.free[i] = make(chan bool)
        d.done[i] = make(chan bool)
    }
    return d
}


func (d *diner) start() {

    for i:=0;i<d.n;i++ {
        go d.fork(i)
        go d.philo(i)
    }



}



func (d *diner) philo(p int) {


    for {
        // think time
        fmt.Printf("%d,think\n",p)
        time.Sleep(d.thinkTime)
        fmt.Printf("%d,hungry\n",p)

        left := false
        right := false
        // check if we can get the left fork
        select {
        case left = <- d.free[p]:
            break
        default:
            left = false
            break
        }

        if !left {
            continue
        }

        //try and get right one
        select {
        case right = <- d.free[((p+1)%d.n)]:
            break
        default:
            right = false
            break
        }

        if !right {
            // then free left as well
            d.done[p] <- true
        }

        if left && right {
            // eat and then release
            fmt.Printf("%d,eat\n",p)
            time.Sleep(d.eatTime)
            // indicate done
            d.done[p] <- true
            d.done[((p+1)%d.n)] <- true
        }

    }

}

func (d *diner) fork(f int) {

    for {

    // indicate that the fork is free
    d.free[f] <- true


    //fmt.Printf("Waiting for fork %d to be done\n",f)
    //wait for it to be used and then released
    select {
    case <- d.done[f]:
        break
    }
    }

}

func main() {

    d := newDiner(5,1*time.Second,4*time.Second)
    d.start()

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    //fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Println(text)
}
```